# open .sql file in jupyter text editor

Tags: jupyter

I'm using a jupyter server and for some reason any .sql that I open is downloaded instead of opened in the text editor. As far as I can tell it's only .sql files that are treated this way, any other file extension is opened by the text editor. Changing the file extension from .sql to anything else will solve the problem, but I want to keep the file extension for syntax highlighting in jupyter and other text editors. Is there a config file somewhere that controls the default file open action?

I'm using jupyter 1.0.0
Ubuntu 16.04 (server and client)
behavior observed in chrome and firefox

update:
it looks related to this issue https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1408
Also upgrading the notebook package to 5.0.0 adds an edit button to the options effectively fixing the issue. But the underlying problem is still there, you can see that by inspecting the .sql link, it's still a file link not an edit link.

to upgrade your notebook use `conda update notebook`

Comment: If I try to open .sql files in Jupyter Lab (on Windows) I get a `File Load Error ... Invalid response: 400 bad format`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: My issue turned out to be because the file was saved with ISO 8859-1 encoding instead of utf-8 and contained a £ symbol.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using jupyter lab instead of notebooks if you are interested in a jupyter text editor.

[blog post](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-is-ready-for-users-5a6f039b8906)

Comment: sql is not mentioned in your link. Please add an explanation as to how jupyter lab would solve this specific problem.